# android.os.TransactionTooLargeException occurs when Writing/Reading JSON with Gson in AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, stack-overflow, gson

In my App, I save E-Mails with GSON to an .json File. Because of freezing the UI, I've to do this in Background. I tried with a "new Thread" but I got a Parsing-Error of Gson, so I'm trying with AsyncTask now...

There my logcat puts out this:

> 03-12 14:36:34.750 30486-30504/at.guger.email I/art: Background sticky
>   concurrent mark sweep GC freed 274498(12MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B)
>   LOS objects, 27% free, 21MB/29MB, paused 5.096ms total 69.641ms 03-12
>   14:36:35.281 30486-30504/at.guger.email I/art: Background sticky
>   concurrent mark sweep GC freed 170008(7MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B)
>   LOS objects, 25% free, 21MB/29MB, paused 5.615ms total 54.870ms 03-12
>   14:36:35.741 30486-30504/at.guger.email I/art: Background sticky
>   concurrent mark sweep GC freed 157620(6MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B)
>   LOS objects, 24% free, 22MB/29MB, paused 5.676ms total 59.539ms 03-12
>   14:36:36.212 30486-30504/at.guger.email I/art: Background partial
>   concurrent mark sweep GC freed 151786(6MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B)
>   LOS objects, 40% free, 22MB/38MB, paused 9.185ms total 107.879ms 03-12
>
> 14:36:37.193 30486-30504/at.guger.email I/art: Background sticky
>   concurrent mark sweep GC freed 355102(14MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B)
>   LOS objects, 24% free, 24MB/32MB, paused 12.054ms total 130.218ms
>
> 03-12 14:36:37.753 30486-30504/at.guger.email I/art: Background sticky
>   concurrent mark sweep GC freed 181500(6MB) AllocSpace objects,
>   97(1195KB) LOS objects, 23% free, 24MB/32MB, paused 8.087ms total
>   105.010ms

This is repeated for maybe 100 times..

Then this is put out:

> 03-12 14:37:02.858 30486-31452/at.guger.email E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL
>   EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #3
>                                                                   Process: at.guger.email, PID: 30486
>                                                                   java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing
>   doInBackground()
>                                                                       at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:304)
>                                                                       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
>                                                                       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
>                                                                       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
>                                                                       at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
>                                                                       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>                                                                       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
>                                                                       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
>                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 1036KB
>                                                                       at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.canonicalize($Gson$Types.java:111)
>                                                                       at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types$WildcardTypeImpl.($Gson$Types.java:553)
>                                                                       at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.canonicalize($Gson$Types.java:111)
>                                                                       at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types$WildcardTypeImpl.($Gson$Types.java:546)
>                                                                       at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.canonicalize($Gson$Types.java:111)
>
> 14:37:03.078 30486-30504/at.guger.email I/art: Background partial
>   concurrent mark sweep GC freed 2071991(33MB) AllocSpace objects,
>   16(10MB) LOS objects, 30% free, 36MB/52MB, paused 2.105ms total
>   219.940ms 03-12 14:37:03.088 30486-31452/at.guger.email D/Error: ERR: exClass=java.lang.StackOverflowError 03-12 14:37:03.088
>   30486-31452/at.guger.email D/Error: ERR: exMsg=stack size 1036KB 03-12
>   14:37:03.088 30486-31452/at.guger.email D/Error: ERR:
>   file=$Gson$Types.java 03-12 14:37:03.088 30486-31452/at.guger.email
>   D/Error: ERR: class=com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types 03-12
>   14:37:03.088 30486-31452/at.guger.email D/Error: ERR:
>   method=canonicalize line=111 03-12 14:37:03.108
>   30486-30499/at.guger.email W/art: Suspending all threads took:
>   10.559ms 03-12 14:37:03.118 30486-31452/at.guger.email D/Error: ERR: stack=java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing
>   doInBackground()
>                                                              at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:304)
>                                                              at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
>                                                              at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
>                                                              at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
>                                                              at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
>                                                              at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>                                                              at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
>                                                              at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
>                                                           Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 1036KB
>                                                              at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.canonicalize($Gson$Types.java:111)
>                                                              at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types$WildcardTypeImpl.($Gson$Types.java:553)
>
> 30486-31452/at.guger.email D/Error: ERR: TOTAL BYTES WRITTEN: 2240396
>   03-12 14:37:03.118 30486-31452/at.guger.email E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED
>   BINDER TRANSACTION !!! 03-12 14:37:03.118 30486-31452/at.guger.email
>   E/AndroidRuntime: Error reporting crash
>                                                                   android.os.TransactionTooLargeException
>                                                                       at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
>                                                                       at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:496)
>                                                                       at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.handleApplicationCrash(ActivityManagerNative.java:4200)
>                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$UncaughtHandler.uncaughtException(RuntimeInit.java:89)
>                                                                       at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:693)
>                                                                       at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:690)

My Code worked if I tried to do it on MainThread:

```
File dir = new File(mailParcel.getContext().getFilesDir() + "/emails/" + mailParcel.getDirectory() + "/" + foldername);

if (!dir.exists()) dir.mkdirs();

for (File f : dir.listFiles()) {
    f.delete();
}

String fileName;
File file;
Mail[] Mails = mailParcel.getMails();

for (int i = 0; i < Mails.length; i++) {
    fileName = Mails[i].getReceiveDate().toString().replace(" ", "_").replace(":", "-");

    try {
        file = new File(dir, fileName + ".json");

        file.createNewFile();

        Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(file));

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
        gson.toJson(Mails[i], writer);

        writer.close();
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
        fnfe.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (UnsupportedEncodingException usee) {
        usee.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I hope you can help me!
If you have another idea instead of for example doing in Asynctask, tell me please!

Comment: If you have a parsing error then changing where the code is executed won't fix anything. It looks like the garbage collector is having trouble keeping up with the task this is most likely due to a circular reference.

Comment: But the code is working if I do it on main thread, that is the confusing part for me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is really simple...

I made an AsyncTask instead of the Thread.
Then the code works.